# Order_By : Django Q objects order?

Tags: django, django-q

I am using operator.or_ and passing Query()objects into it. The Query()objects contains 3 queries i.e,

1. by name
2. by description
3. by title

when I am getting output the results not coming in order ? like I want first priority by name then description and then title ?

Here is sample code

```
def search(self, search_terms, filters, category=False, vendor=False):
    terms = [term.strip() for term in search_terms.split()]
    q_objects = []
    if terms:
        for term in terms:
                q_objects.append(Q(name__icontains=search_terms))
                q_objects.append(Q(description__icontains=search_terms))
                q_objects.append(Q(title__icontains=search_terms))
    qs = self.get_query_set()
    if len(q_objects) > 1:
        return qs.filter(reduce(operator.or_, q_objects))
    else:
        return qs
```

So can any one help this to search order by name first after that by description and then title ?

Thanks In Advance !

Answer (score 3):

Ordering is done by [`QuerySet.order_by`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.order_by), so in addition to filtering the queryset, do:

```
qs = qs.order_by('name', 'description', 'title')
```

Comment: Thanks, It used for me